# How to return a default property of JS literal object?

Tags: javascript, properties, object-literal

One JS object is defined like this:

```
var obj = {
      key1 : {on:'value1', off:'value2'},
      key2 : {on:'value3', off:'value4'}
}
```

Is there a tricky way, to pick a default `key1` `on` property, when the `obj.key1` is passed without property?

```
var key1State = obj.key1; // I want to receive 'value1' here, not obj.key1{...}
```

Is it somehow generally possible to recognize in the object definition body which property (if at all) is passed/asked during the object call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but messing with `valueOf` or `toString` may be what you're looking for.

For example:

```
var obj = {
      key1 : {on:'value1', off:'value2', toString : function(){ return this.on; }},
      key2 : {on:'value3', off:'value4', toString : function(){ return this.on; }}
}

var key1State = obj.key1; // the object
var key1StateStr = '' + obj.key1; // string "value1"
obj.key1 == "value1"  // true
obj.key1.toString() === "value1"  // true
```

So if you were going to use the default value as a string somewhere this may be useful.

Comment: This is very useful, +1. Does this work (and only then) because `toString()` is called implicitely every time an object is used in a `String` context? Like `console.log(\`${obj.key1}\`)` or `let value = '' + obj.key1`.

Comment: Yes, implicit type conversion is what's at play here.

Answer (score 1):

This does not fix your case, but you may find it useful.

Use getters.

```
var obj = {

  key1 : {on:'value1', off:'value2'},
  key2 : {on:'value3', off:'value4'}, 
  get fooBar () { return this.key1.on }

}
```

now obj.fooBar returns keyq.on

Comment: Or use `get key1()` `set key1(value)` etc. (removing/renaming `key1` itself)

Answer (score 0):

I am understand your idea, but think the better way here is to use function like `getState` for getting actual state of object.

```
var obj = {
  key1: {on:'value1', off:'value2'},
  key2: {on:'value3', off:'value4'}
};

var key1State = getState(obj.key1);
var key2State = getState(obj.key2.off);

function getState(obj) {
  return obj.on || obj;
}

console.log(key1State, key2State);
```

[See codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CwDga)